# How to include OpenCV in pyinstaller when opencv is installed from source?

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson

I have installed OpenCV 4.1 in Jetson Nano from source. It works perfect when i run my python3 code. After compiling python code using pyinstaller it throws ImportError.

```
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

How do I compile python code using PyInstaller to make OpenCV included? Is there any other method to install OpenCV? I have tried `pip3 install opencv-python` but it does not find the matching distribution and if I install using `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv` it installs an older version.
Any help wou.d be helpful.

I have also followed this thread but it does not work when OpenCV is compiled from source...

Comment: Try `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: @coffeewin Thanks for the comment, Tried that but still no luck, Error No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I found the following solution:

Python 3.6

OpenCV 4.1 (Compiled from source)

pyinstaller 3.5

1. Get the path of OpenCV

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__file__) # /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.so
```

2. Add this path while compiling through pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller main.py -n myApp --paths="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6"
```

I hope this helps others also