# Nuitka include OpenCV compiled from source: OpenCV ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python, opencv, nuitka

I have installed OpenCV v4.1.1 from source. I have successfully created binary file using Nuitka. After that when I run the binary file it produces Import Error.

```
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

Compiled with the following command:

```
python3 -m nuitka --standalone --plugin-enable=pylint-warnings --plugin-enable=numpy --plugin-enable=pkg-resources --remove-output --python-flag=no_site main.py
```

**Environment information**

- Platform: Jetson Nano running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Python Version: 3.6.9
- OpenCV 4.1.1 (compiled from source)
- Nuitka 0.6.15 installed through PIP3

There is another similar question here in stackoverflow using Pyinstaller in the follwing link: [How to include OpenCV in pyinstaller when opencv is installed from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189791/how-to-include-opencv-in-pyinstaller-when-opencv-is-installed-from-source)

I would like to solve it using Nuitka.